# How to handle the socket exception in python and continue the script execution?

Tags: sockets, try-catch, python-3.6

i am trying to get the status returns from list of domains using socket. Here if socket coudln't resolve any random domain due to any case, its stopping the execution there itself  and not consider to resolve further from the list

```
def getDate_andTime():
  return 'time'

def get_HostName(domainName):
    value = socket.gethostbyname_ex(domainName)
    try:
        if not str(value[0]).startswith("[Errno") and str(value[0] !=''):
            return True, value[0],getDate_andTime()
        elif str(value[0]).startswith("[Errno"):
            print("Value is not available")
            return False, value[0], getDate_andTime()
    except socket.gaierror as e:
        print("Error log", socket.gaierror)
    return False,e, getDate_andTime()


#Invoking the method
listofdomain=['abc.com','bcd.com','ade.com']
for domain in listofdomain:
    condition, value, time= get_HostName(domain)
```

Here if 'bcd.com' not resolved, the script is stopping without considering the 'ade.com' even i have catch the exception.

Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push the return statement inside the `except` block. Scope of exception variable `e` is inside the except block only.

**Ex:**

```
def get_HostName(domainName):
    try:
        value = socket.gethostbyname_ex(domainName)
        if not str(value[0]).startswith("[Errno") and str(value[0] !=''):
            return True, value[0],getDate_andTime()
        elif str(value[0]).startswith("[Errno"):
            print("Value is not available")
            return False, value[0], getDate_andTime()
    except socket.gaierror as e:
        print("Error log", socket.gaierror)
        return False,e, getDate_andTime()
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, i tried in the same way you suggested, but still getting "socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed" error

Comment: Looks like you also need to push `value = socket.gethostbyname_ex(domainName)` inside the `try`

Comment: Even  i tired the similar way.. but still getting the similar issue